# Split TIMESTAMPTZ into DATE and TIME via generated columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "foo" (
    -- ...
    "startTimestamp" TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    -- ...
)
```

and it is now a requirement that this timestamp will be stored in the database as separate `DATE` and `TIME` columns. I would like to avoid having to change the client code that accesses this table, so my idea was to use generated columns like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "foo" (
    -- ...
    "startTimestamp" TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    "startDate" DATE NOT NULL ALWAYS GENERATED AS ("startTimestamp"::DATE),
    "startTime" TIME NOT NULL ALWAYS GENERATED AS ("startTimestamp"::TIME),
    -- ...
)
```

However, this fails with the error "generation expression is not immutable", which, from what I can tell is because the typecast may rely on local timezone settings.

Is there a way to circumvent this and make the generated columns work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for casting, the database can do this automatically for you. This set up works:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "foo" (
    "startTimestamp" TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    "startDate" DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("startTimestamp") STORED,
    "startTime" TIME GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("startTimestamp") STORED
);

INSERT INTO foo("startTimestamp") 
VALUES(NOW())
RETURNING *;
```

There is no need for the NOT NULL constraints on "startDate" and "startTime". You can't fill these columns manually and the source "startTimestamp" already has a NOT NULL constraint.